# How to prove convex linear combination rule.

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, convex-analysis

Let $x_i, i=1\dots n$ be elements of a convex subset $K$ of a linear space $X$ over the reals.  Then any linear combination $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i x_i$ such that $a_i \geq 0$ and $\sum a_i = 1$ is also in the convex set.

My attempt involves first trying to prove it for the case $n = 3$.  Let $x = a_1 x_1 + \dots a_3 x_3$, then one of the conditions gives $a_3 = 1 - a_2 - a_1$ so we have $a_1 x_1 + (1 - a_1)x_3 + a_2 (x_2 - x_3) = x$, the first two terms summing to an element of $K$ since $K$ is convex.  I thought I had the next step on paper, but lost it and didn't take good notes.  What's next?

Comment: The set of all such linear combinations is called the *convex hull* of the $x_i$'s. You can show that it's the smallest convex set which contains all the $x_i$'s.

Comment: Maybe this: https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Anatoli.Iouditski/cours/convex/chapitre_1.pdf would be usefull :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume your definition of convexity is as follows: $K$ is said to be convex if whenever $x,y$ are in $K$, so too is $tx+(1-t)y$ for all $0\leq t\leq 1$.
In this case, we can proceed by induction:

> To prove the claim by induction, suppose that any [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of $n$ points is in the set.
>  Now, consider a convex combination of $n + 1$ points, $\sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} t_i x_i$.
>  By simple algebra, we can rewrite this as
>  \begin{align*}\sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} t_i x_i & = t_{n+1}x_{n+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_{i}x_{i} \\ &=t_{n+1}x_{n+1}+\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}t_{j}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{t_{i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}t_{j}}x_{i}\right)\\ & =t_{n+1}x_{n+1}+\left(1-t_{n+1}\right)\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{t_{i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}t_{j}}x_{i}\right)}_{y}.\end{align*}
>  In the last line, we have used the fact that $\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}t_{j}=1$.
>  From the induction hypothesis, we know that $y$ is in the set since it is a convex combination of $n$ points.
>  Therefore, the above reduces to a convex combination of two points ($x_{n + 1}$ and $y$), which we know is in the set by the definition of a convex set.

Comment: How though, I tried induction...

Comment: Suppose that for some $n\geq 2$, all $n$-point convex combinations are contained in the set. Try to show that all $(n+1)$-point  convex combinations are contained in the set too.

Comment: Okay, I meant that I tried that.  I'll try again...

Comment: Hint: $(t_1 x_1 + \cdots + t_n x_n)+t_{n+1} x_{n+1}$ and $t_{n+1}=1-(t_1+\cdots+t_n)$.

Comment: Still not seeing, it I've seen everything you've said so far though.

Comment: Like I said, I've got all that so far.

Comment: OMG, thanks.  Don't know how I kept skipping by it.  I even tried that out...

Comment: How would one go about coming up with this proof?

Comment: @JKEG: Try to break down the problem into smaller parts. The case of $n=2$ is true by definition of a convex set. Can you do the case of $n=3$? $n=4$? Once you've completed these cases, can you generalize the argument to any $n > 2$?

Comment: I would like to ask how this is a valid proof. Assuming $t_{n+1} \in ( 0,1 )$ (where the proof is trivial if $t_{n+1} \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$), you’re then claiming $\sum^{n}_{i=1}(\frac{t_i}{\sum^{n}_{j=1}(t_j)}x_{i}) $ is in the set which was never explicitly stated neither by induction nor problem statement.

Comment: @Chloe I also have the same doubt... I reached till the part of proof myself... but We need to show the mentioned point belongs to The set to complete the proof...

Comment: @Chloe I think the proof is valid. $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{t_i}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}(t_j)}x_i)$ is in the set because by the induction hypothesis, since the sum of its coefficients equals 1 and is a convex combination of $x_1,...,x_n$, it belongs in the convex set.

Comment: Jambon Au Chocolat is correct. I have rewritten the answer to hopefully be more accessible.